# transpose and if - excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID  NAME
70307   Name 1
70307   Name 2
80694   Name 1
80694   Name 2
80694   Name 3
80694   Name 4
80694   Name 5
80694   Name 6
88692   Name 1
88692   Name 2
240676  Name 1
240676  Name 2
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
ID        A       B       C      D       E        F 
70307   Name 1  Name 2              
70307                       
80694   Name 1  Name 2  Name 3  Name 4  Name 5  Name 6
80694                       
80694                       
80694                       
80694                       
80694                       
88692   Name 1  Name 2          
88692                       
240676  Name 1  Name 2              
240676
```

Maybe, if possible, remove the duplicates in the process.

Is there any way I can make this?

Thanks!

Comment: formulas will not remove a value from a cell, or move a value, but only report the value that is referenced.

Comment: At least to transpose them according to their ID in the order they are in the table, is that possible?

Comment: Unless you need  a non VBA solution (you didn't say it) for this Q, then this Q is a duplicate. ( :